# What is the difference between class="example" vs. classNames="example" in Ember/handlebars components?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm applying a class to a component, and it seems like both of these options work:

1. `{{example-component class="example-class"}}`
2. `{{example-component classNames="example-class"}}`

Both ultimately result in the rendered HTML having the class, e.g.:

`<div class="example-class ember-view">...</div>`

Is there a difference between providing the class via `class` or `classNames`? Are there any unintended consequences using one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no important difference, except that class should be a string and classNames should be an array of strings.

If you pass a class at invocation time at .hbs, I recommend using class property as in your first example, because it is the same way you would specify a class for a regular HTML element.

Property classNames can be used at .js file. 
I.e. I often use a pattern like that:

```
// my-small-button.js
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  classNames: ['my-button', 'small']
});
```

Invocation of component:

```
{{my-small-button class="red"}}
```

Result-html:

```
<div class="my-button small red">
</div
```